# Wanted API codes to download files of particular extension from Windchill

Tags: ptc-windchill

Can any one help me with the code to download all files of particular extension (say *.prt or *.asm) from windchill to local. Please suggest suitable API

Answer (score 1):

It's not really the way Windchill works... Windchill is a PDM software, so you should first search for the correct metadata (certainly EPMDocument in your case), and then get the attach files. You'll have to specify the type of attachment you want to have (primary, secondary content, etc.)

=> you need to understand the datamodel and specify what you really want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a query using queryspec and sort. The download part Im not sure about, but it is possible.